# Can Azure Devops Server provision hardware

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server, azure-devops-server-2020

I know that you can apply ARM templates to create VM's via Azure Devops Services, but can it be done on prem using Azure Devops Server?

or is it just a matter of building a pipeline with powershell to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> can it be done on prem using Azure Devops Server?

Yes.  Azure Devops Server supports applying ARM templates to create VM too.

The operation on the local Azure Devops Server is similar to the operation on Azure Devops Service.

Here are the steps:

Step 1: Create an ARM template and upload it to Repo in Azure Devops Server.

Step 2: Create an Azure Resource Manager service connection.
[image]

Step 3:  Setup Release. Use the Azure resource group deployment task to deploy an Azure VM via ARM Template.

[image]

Here is a doc about [CD of an Azure virtual machine using a Resource Manager template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/azure/deploy-provision-azure-vm?view=azure-devops-2019)

Comment: Thanks Kevin, but I'd like to create a vm on our own infrastructure, rather than in azure.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean to use ARM-like templates to create VMs on servers other than Azure？

Comment: That would certainly be one way to describe it.

Comment: Hi @Trubs. If you want to deploy to a private infrastructure, I'm afraid there is no method out of the box(e.g. existing pipeline task) to achieve it. You need to write a script to achieve it.